# Styling all but the first selected element?

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors, web-component

I'm selecting custom elements like this:

```
app-csv-header-selection {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

And that works fine.  I'd also like to exclude the styling from the first element selected.

Is this possible without also involving a parent container?

A pseudo example would be something like:

```
app-csv-header-selection:not(:first) {
    margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Your CSS is missing a designation of class or id.  Can you please add the html you are trying to operate on?

Comment: It's targeting custom angular elements (`app-csv-header-selection`)

Comment: It's close - but ideally the answer would not have to use a first container.  Any time we are doing `first-child` the parent container is the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app-csv-header-selection:not(:first-of-type) {
        margin-left: 2rem;
}
```

Works.  The reason for using `first-of-type` is to make sure only `app-csv-header-selection` elements are included in the selection.

Comment: It seems like that should work, but I just tried it and the margin is still applied to the first element.

Comment: Good try though - Not sure who down voted it - but I voted it back up, because I also thought it should work.

Comment: For no parent container, `:not(:first-of-type)` is the right answer.  If there's more going on --such as dynamic elements-- please add more details to your question.

Comment: @jmargolisvt you nailed it!  I'm going to modify this answer a little bit to include your comment.  THANK YOU!